# Sort SOLR query by one field if date is between two dates, otherwise by different field

Tags: sorting, solr

I have 4 fields in my SOLR documents:

- price: float, indexed, stored
- special_price: float, indexed, stored
- special_price_from: date, indexed, stored
- special_price_to: date, indexed, stored

I want to sort by `special_price` if current date is between `special_price_from` and `special_price_to`. If not, I want it sorted by `price`.

As far as I understood, FunctionQueries are evaluated per document.

I've tried different sort expressions, neither of them worked. I couldn't even get it to work without the timeframe:

```
sort=if(special_price,special_price,price) asc
```

or

```
sort=def(special_price,price) asc
```

or (with and without string literal)

```
sort=query($qq)+asc&qq=if(special_price,"special_price","price")
```

Maybe I'm thinking too much in MySQL terms but I just can't figure it out.

I'm using SOLR 3.6.2.